# ggplot heatmap where axis scaling is proportional to other variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I found this figure: [Heatmap with variable box sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q89bd.png) in this article: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/2378023118805646

Does anyone know how to make a heatmap where the size of the boxes varies?

This

```
# Library
library(ggplot2)

# Dummy data
x <- LETTERS[1:20]
y <- paste0("var", seq(1,20))
data <- expand.grid(X=x, Y=y)
data$Z <- runif(400, 0, 5)

# Heatmap 
ggplot(data, aes(X, Y, fill= Z)) + 
  geom_tile()
```

gives me a heatmap, but no clue how to fix the axes scales so that they follow a different variable.

Thanks
Hasan

Answer (score 0):

A heatmap with varying box sizes can be achieved via `geom_rect`. Depending on your data this requires more or less manual work to set up or compute the boundaries of the boxes, i.e. the values used for the `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` aesthetics. Try this:

```r
# Library
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

# Dummy data
x <- LETTERS[1:5]
y <- paste0("var", seq(1,5))
# Lower and upper bounds of rectangles
xx <- setNames(cumsum(runif(5)), x)
xx1 <- setNames(c(0, xx[1:4]), x)
yy <- setNames(cumsum(runif(5)), y)
yy1 <- setNames(c(0, yy[1:4]), y)
data <- expand.grid(X=x, Y=y)
data$Z <- runif(25, 0, 5)
data$xmax <- xx[data$X]
data$ymax <- yy[data$Y]
data$xmin <- xx1[data$X]
data$ymin <- yy1[data$Y]

# Heatmap 
ggplot(data, aes(fill= Z)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), color = "white") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = (xx1 + xx) / 2, labels = x) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = (yy1 + yy) / 2, labels = y) +
  scale_fill_viridis_b()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>